# Coruppted Jenkins need to reinstall

Tags: jenkins

My jenkins looks like corrupted. After installing older version I tried to upgrade. When I tried

```
wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

It was failed to upgrade. Then I removed jenkins using

```
sudo apt-get remove jenkins
```

And again I tried to install.It is giving

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jenkins is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjna-java libhttpcore-java libxbean-java libargs4j-java libhttpclient-java
  libplexus-build-api-java libbackport-util-concurrent-java
  libplexus-utils-java libjffi-java libjffi-jni
  libmaven-common-artifact-filters-java libjsr305-java libcommons-jexl-java
  libplexus-bsh-factory-java libplexus-container-default-java
  libganymed-ssh2-java jenkins-cli libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java
  libcommons-net2-java libjsoup-java libmaven2-core-java libplexus-cipher-java
  libjenkins-remoting-java libeasymock-java libplexus-i18n-java
  libmaven-invoker-java libplexus-containers-java libjaffl-java libdoxia-java
  libmaven-dependency-tree-java libmodello-java libplexus-archiver-java
  libconstantine-java libmaven-scm-java libmaven-enforcer-plugin-java
  libplexus-io-java libwagon-java libcommons-vfs-java libanimal-sniffer-java
  libgoogle-collections-java libnetbeans-cvsclient-java
  libmaven-plugin-testing-java libplexus-classworlds-java libitext1-java
  libplexus-interactivity-api-java libcommons-jxpath-java jenkins-common
  libplexus-interpolation-java libclassworlds-java
  libcommons-configuration-java libjnr-posix-java libplexus-ant-factory-java
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 513 not upgraded.
```

But `service jenkins restart` command throwing

```
jenkins: unrecognized service
```

Even `http://localhost:8080/` not working.

I want to install from beginning . Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
sudo dpkg -P jenkins
```

and then re-install